# Changing Wifi Network without rebooting

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch

After successfully setting up a network using `wpa_supplicant.conf`, how can I change the network and have the changes take effect without rebooting? After editing `wpa_supplicant.conf` it seems no matter what I do I can't connect to the new network unless I reboot.

Tried in all possible permutations:

- `wpa_cli reconfigure wlan0`
- stopping/starting/restarting `dhcpcd` and `avahi-daemon`
- `ip addr flush dev wlan0`
- `ifconfig wlan0 up/down`

If it matters, I'm using a Wifi dongle and disabling the onboard Wifi with a line in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` -- `denyinterfaces wlan1`

Rebooting always works and `wlan0` will succesfully connect to the new network. I want to try to avoid this reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Typically after changing the configuration file for a system daemon, it is necessary to restart the daemon to get it to re-read the configuration file.

You don't mention the Linux version you are running. If you're using "systemd" system, modify wpa_supplicant.conf and enter "sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service".  I'm not sure about the interface between wpa_supplicant and DHCP, so you might need to stop the network service, restart wpa_supplicant, and then start the network service.